# Composer installation, stuck at "Running the Composer installer script"

Tags: php, dependencies, composer-php

I've downloaded Composer from their official website and when running the installer it always gets stuck at the last part "Running the Composer installer script". Although if I wait long enough about 10-20 minutes, it will show that the installer cannot fetch the "installer script" from their website that is needed . This is also happening to my friend, as well as a computer laboratory near my place.

Comment: I think the problem is your poor computer network connection. Try checking the Internet connection or using another network connection

Comment: Not really, i have a pretty reliable internet.